# Trouble deploying Ethereum contract to live network (Truffle)

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment, truffle-compile

When trying to deploy to the Ethereum main net I am getting the error:

> Deploying Migrations...
>   ... undefined
>
> Error encountered, bailing.
>   Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
>
> Error:
>   insufficient funds for gas * price + value

However, I am able to deploy it to Rinkeby fine and definitely have enough funds.

I am running my ethereum node on an AWS EC2 instance and then I ssh into that instance to try to compile and deploy.

My truffle.js:

```
live: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: 1,
      gas: 4700000,
      gasLimit: 2000000000,
      from: "ACCOUNT_NUMBER"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always the little things!

In my truffle.js I specified a parameter as GasLimit instead of GasPrice